# Why nginx for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

Why using nginx?

That simple question, I couldn't figure out and I guess my understanding about proxy network and cloud VM is not sufficient enough. 
I have been using EC2 for the past few months deploy several websites via localhost of the instance.
To my understanding the Public DNS should map to that localhost.
Or if there is a need of configuration in between that makes sense too. But why have to be nginx.

Can I use other tool, if yes what are they? 
And can I deploy without even a proxy in between meaning mapping public DNS directly to its localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your question is "why do I need a (reverse) proxy server", right? It doesn't make much difference if you're on EC2 or not and nginx is just one (very popular) proxy server.

There are more than enough articles on the reverse proxy topic, for example [The Benefits of a Reverse Proxy](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/the-benefits-of-reverse-proxy.html).

So no, nginx is not required, but it's a popular choice for a reverse proxy. If it's worth the effort depends on your use case.

Comment: if you say nginx is optional, that mean we can map EC2 public dns directly to its localhost, could you give me a pointer on how can I do that? Thanks . Because without nginx, if I visit my public dns, it returns an error page, and my webserver is deploy at port localhost:8080

Comment: The "we can map EC2 public dns directly to its localhost" confuses me a little. I assume you have a domain, for example test.example.com. Now the test subdomain should be a CNAME and point to the public DNS of the EC2 instance. If your server runs on port 80, opening test.example.com in your browser should show the correct content

Comment: I first deploy my web server at port 8080 and use the public dns ec2 provided, but it doesn't show my content. Is there a different between port 80 and 8080, because you say port 80 should show my website.

Comment: If you use port 8080 you will need to open test.example.com:8080 in your browser. The default port for HTTP is 80 and for HTTPS 443. So you can run your app on 8080 and proxy it through nginx running on 80. Or you can run your app on port 80 directly without nginx